# How can i throw exception if processing don't response

Tags: c++, multithreading, timeout

I have c++ clr project.
It use API a company(like solidworks' api).

So..My problem is happened here.

```
BOOL rc = m_pc3dCore->Login(m_CdmUser, m_CdmUserPass, m_CdmServer);
```

That try to Login the other server appication.
But if That application doesn't working, Doesn't any response. I can't advance next source. Debuger Stay infinitly "m_pc3dCore->Login(m_CdmUser, m_CdmUserPass, m_CdmServer);"

So, I did to wrap that to use try{} catch(...){}
But didn't change anything.

I want to throw Exception, If it stay there 4second.
Can you teach me how can i solve this or keyword for searching?

--- my opinion 
I thought that i solve this using System::Thread Interface.
So i tried to make a method. The method do loop infinitly.

```
void threadFuncA()
{
    while(true){
    }
}
```

And Make Thread

```
Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(threadFuncA));
newThread->Start();
newThread->Join();
```

Program start infinity loop after called newThread->Join();
Is it be solution exit loop?

- I can't try to use m_pc3dCore->Login(m_CdmUser, m_CdmUserPass, m_CdmServer);
  Because that server is working now, so return True. As a result i can't happen problem. It is the reason that i made infinite loop method.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a UNIX system, you can interrupt a blocking system call by a signal.
try:

```
alarm(4);
BOOL rc = m_pc3dCore->Login(m_CdmUser, m_CdmUserPass, m_CdmServer);
alarm(0);
```

after 4 seconds a blocking situation is interrupted and the program goes on.
First install a self written handler(int) for diagnosis of this situation:

```
signal(SIGALRM, handler);
```

or use sigaction() on a modern UNIX.

Comment: Thank you i solved yeaster day using thread.join(int msec). But i think that using alarm can solute also.

Answer (score 0):

If the call to `Login()` won't return on a timeout itself, you'll probably need to implement some sort of polling.

[Here](http://bitsquid.blogspot.com/2011/02/managing-decoupling-part-2-polling.html) is an article about polling, callbacks, and events. And [here](https://rubentorresbonet.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/c-11-stop-polling-long-live-stdcondition_variable/) is an article about some newer language features that may help you achieve your objective. Hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.